# Changing behavior in Mac Terminal (e.g. wildcards don't work)

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, command-line-interface

Let me preface this by saying I've read enough to believe this has something to do with the login terminal and .bashprofile, etc. But I don't understand enough about the underpinnings of the Mac terminal to be able to solve this.

When my prompt reads

```
my-mac:~ [username]$
```

... where [username] is my login name, I generally type in

```
cd doc*
```

to go into my Documents folder. However, occasionally this command doesn't work.  For instance right now I am getting the result

```
bash: cd: doc*: No such file or directory
```

Even when I close and reopen Terminal, I'm still getting this error. Can someone please help me understand both how to fix this and the root cause of why this happens?

Comment: When it isn't working, what do you get if you do `ls -la doc*`? It could be that there is another doc* file being expanded into the cd command

Comment: When I do `ls -la doc*` I also get `No such file or directory` but when I do `ls` I get the contents and Documents is present, but there are no other directories or files that start with "doc"

Comment: I think its a case sensitivity problem - if you do `cd Doc*` with a capital D it will work

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I could have sworn that I generally do not capitalize and the wildcarded term still works. I still believe there is differing behavior between various terminal windows based on if it is a login shell or not (still not completely sure what that means...)

Comment: I think you can do this `shopt -s nocaseglob` as found here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2799027?start=0&tstart=0 - I'm away from my Mac so can't test it. I'm not sure if there are differences between the login shell and terminals